# The first element of my output is wrong where I want to write a C function that takes an array as input and reverse it

Tags: c, arrays

I want to write a C function that takes an array as input and reverse it but the first element of the output is wrong so I'd like to understand the analysis for this issue output. For example if I enter `[34 3 2 1 12 ]` the output  is `[32766 12 1 2 3 ]`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse_array(int arr[],int n);
#define size 5

int main()
{
 int i=0;
 int arr[size];

 //scan  array from user     
 printf("please enter elements of array:\n");
 for(i=0;i<size;i++)
 {
   scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
 }

 //call fun
 printf("the  reverse  array is :");
 reverse_array(arr,size);

}

 //define function     
void reverse_array(int arr[], int n)
{
   int i=n;

   for(i<=n;i>0;i--)
   {
     printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: If an aray is size of `n` then its last element index is `n-1`. Also your `for` is weird. The first part `i<=n` has no effect. You should write `int i = n - 1` there instead. And get rid of `int i=n;`.

Comment: you are accessing arr[5] which does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do that

```
void reverse_array(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;

    for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)      //i=n-1 i.e 4, it runs 4,3,2,1,0
    {
      printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This cycle

```
for(i<=n;i>0;i--)
{
  printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
}
```

Is not correct. The first printed element is out of the bounds of the array thus invoking undefined behaviour, in you case it prints `32766`, in mine it prints `0`.

Try:

```
while(i-- > 0)
{
  printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
}
```

[**Live sample**](https://onlinegdb.com/S1nTpMRr8)

Note that you are only reverse printing it, if that's what you need, that's fine, if you need to save it you need a bit more work.

Comment: but 32766 means that i print arr[5] which mot be defined in my code so it should be arr[n-1]

Comment: @sarahamdy, it prints `arr[5]`, you say `i = n`, that's 5, and then you print it before decrementing, note that in my fix `i` is decremented before the node is printed, thus printing `arr[5-1]`.

Comment: @sarahamdy, also note that the first field in your for loop `i<=n` is not correct, it should be `i = n` or in the case of corrected code `i = n-1`,

Answer (score 0):

You are "only" printing the array elements, when you probably wanted to actually reverse the order inside the array.

The classical way is something like this:

```
void reverse_array(int arr[], int n)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
  {
    const int j = (n - 1) - i;
    const int k = arr[j];
    arr[j] = arr[i];
    arr[i] = k;
  }
}
```

This reverses the array in-place by swapping elements.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues

> > The first one the initialization of i should be int i=n-1; not int i=n; as arr[n] doesn't exist 
> >     Secondly for loop should loops till i>=0 not i>0 as arr[0] willn't be printed if iteration works only till i>0

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse_array(int arr[],int n);
#define size 5

int main()
{
 int i=0;
int arr[size];
//scan  array from user
printf("please enter elements of array:\n");
           for(i=0;i<size;i++)
                     {
              scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
                      }
//call fun
printf("the  reverse  array is :");
reverse_array(arr,size);


}
//define function
void reverse_array(int arr[], int n)
{
int i;

for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
{
  printf("%d\t",arr[i]);
}

}
```